# Таймер обратного отсчета

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! как сделать таймер обратного отсчета? То-есть, чтобы таймер выводил секунды в обратном порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Идея такая:

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
final long duration = 30000;
new Thread() {
     public void run() {
         long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
         while (now > start + duration) {
             try {
                 sleep(1000);
             } catch (InteruptedException e) {
             }
             now = System.currentTimeMillis();
             System.out.println((now - start) / 1000); // или как-то по-другому выводим секунды
         }
     }
}.start();
```

Код не до конца доработан. Есть вероятность, что поток выйдет из состояния паузы не по окончании работы метода `sleep`, а по другим причинам (если какой-нибудь другой поток выведет его из спячки). При этом выкинется `InterruptedException`. Тогда два отсчёта подряд будут выводиться одинаковые значения, а время отсчёта сместится. Как этого избежать, думайте сами.